# Linking Angular Material Progress bar to Observable value

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I'm trying to link a progress bar to an HTTP POST event. So that I can show the upload progress to my user. I currently have this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-progress-snackbar',
  template: `<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progress"></mat-progress-bar>`,
  styles: [],
})
export class UploadProgressComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data) { }

  public UploadObservable;

  public progress = 0;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.UploadObservable = this.data.uploadProgress;

    this.UploadObservable.subscribe((event) => {
      // Don't change value after finished upload
      if (event.loaded !== undefined) {
        // Convert progress to percentage and integer
        this.progress = Math.trunc(event.loaded / (event.total || event.loaded) * 100);

        this.progress.valueOf();
      }
      // Log upload progress
      console.log(this.progress);
    });
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure if it has something to do with scope or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the async pipe to directly subscribe from within the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-progress-snackbar',
  template: `<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progress | async"></mat-progress-bar>`,
  styles: [],
})
export class UploadProgressComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data) { }

  public progress = this.data.uploadProgress.pipe(
    map(({ loaded, total }) => loaded ? Math.round(loaded / (total || loaded) * 100) : 0)
  );
}
```